# What changes will be made to arcpy in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I heard that two big changes to arcpy will be add-ins and new, faster cursors. Also, new features include "the ability to administer your enterprsie geodatabase (ArcSDE) using Python scripting" and "Dynamic legend creation." I was wondering if anyone knew of other specific changes, maybe something overheard at the 2011 user conference. A changelog of all the changes would be ideal, but I haven't had luck finding anything.

Comment: This is a little too speculative and invites debate. You already know what ESRI said will be there. Anything else is speculation. Once it is released this question will be moot.

Comment: @Sean Yes, and it's a temporally localized question.  Nevertheless, it has interest to many GIS people.  Why not carry on the discussion in chat?  (Almost anyone can create a chat room.)

Answer (score 2):

I have just been told, that 10.1 will address memory leaking, which is an issue, although the fact that aggregatePoints no longer works in SP2, may not be addressed.

Comment: No comment on the downvote?  What didn't you like?  ESRI person perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

My Esri rep told us multiple times that you will be able to attach ArcPy scripts to buttons (like you can with VB) but I have not found any written documentation of that.  Other than that what you listed are the only features I have heard touted as of now.